# Error while saving transformation in pentaho spoon

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I am getting below error while I save the transformation in pentaho spoon:

```
Error saving transformation to repository!

Error updating batch
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.R_STEP_ATTRIBUTE' with unique index 'IDX_RSAT'. The duplicate key value is (2314, PARTITIONING_SCHEMA, 0).
```

Everything was working fine before I ran a job that creates multiple excel files. While this job was running suddenly a memory issue occurred and the job was aborted. After that I tried to save my file but it is deleted for saving but not been saved. So I lost the job I created.

Please help me to know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last save of the directory did not end gracefully.

There is a small chance that you can repair it by easing the db-caches file in the .kettle directory.

If it does not work, create a new repository and copy the current in the new. Try the global repository export/import. Then erase the old rep and do the same from the just rebuild repository.

The intermediary repository may be on files rather than on a database.

If it is the first time you do this, plan for a one-two hours.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to recover this.

As AlainD says, the problem occurs when you save or delete a transformations, and suddenly you lost the connection or had a problem with Kettle.

When that occurs, you will find a lot of step records into the table `R_STEP_ATTRIBUTE`. In the error shown is the `[ID_TRANSFORMATION] = 2314`.

So, if you check the table `R_TRANSFORMATION` with `[ID_TRANSFORMATION] = 2314`, maybe wont find any transformation with that id.

After check that, you can delete all the records related with that [ID_TRANSFORMATION], for example:

```
delete from R_STEP_ATTRIBUTE where ID_TRANSFORMATION=2314
```

Answer (score 0):

We just solved this issue by executing the following SQL statement

```
DELETE 
FROM R_STEP_ATTRIBUTE
WHERE ID_STEP NOT IN (SELECT ID_STEP FROM R_STEP)
```